# How to Dynamically name a Hash key in Ruby

Tags: ruby, dynamic, hash, key, erb

I'm trying to make a 'render' call in an erb file where the key of the hash is dynamically named. For example...

```
<% object_type_abbr = ["pos", "job_description", "policy", "procedure", "step", "task", "product"] %>

<%= render path.to_s, 
        model_id: @model.id,
        object_type_abbr[i]: orphan,
        row_no: row_no,  
        is_orphan: true 
%>
```

The problem is this syntax is not recognized. I have tried using the #{ruby var name} syntax (suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21321886/dynamically-creating-hash-key-name-in-rails-4)), but of course this doesn't work in HTML.

I've also tried object_type_abbr[i].to_sym, which makes no difference.

I know this has to exist, but can't find it.

Comment: `to_sym` returns something like `:pos`, so you are writing: `:pos: orphan`, which is not syntax that you should have learned anywhere.  And because `pos: orphan` is shorthand for `:pos => orphan`...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

One solution is to use the `=>` notation for that entry in the hash e.g.

```
model_id: @model.id
object_type_abbr[i].to_sym => orphan,
....
```

The standard way to map keys to values in a hash is using the `key => value` (rocket) notation.

When you write `model_id: @model.id` this is shorthand for `:model_id => @model.id` - Ruby provides this shorthand because creating hashes where the keys are symbols is such a common use case. But it isn't valid to use this style of syntax for something like `object_type_abbr[i]:` where the thing of the left of the colon isn't the name for a symbol.

When you use the `=>` notation the key can be any expression, including one that evaluates to a symbol.

Comment: Wow, can't believe that actually worked. Thanks! Why does that work?

Comment: @Taylor I've added a bit of explanation. Let me know if that clears it up for you!